# Trouble with Nuxt Content Module, Vitest, nuxt unit test and Test Setup

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vitest, nuxt-content

I'm encountering issues while trying to set up unit tests for my Nuxt application using the Nuxt Content module and Vitest. Here's a breakdown of my situation:

I have a Nuxt application using the Nuxt Content module.
I'm attempting to create a unit test in content.test.ts.

```
// content.test.ts
import { describe, expect, test } from 'vitest'
import { setup, mount } from '@nuxt/test-utils'
import HelloWorld from '../pages/helloWork.vue'
import App from '../app.vue'

describe('my test', async () => {
  await setup({
    // ... configuration options
  })

  const wrapper = mount(HelloWorld)

  test('works', async () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

My HelloWorld component looks like this:

```
<!-- helloWork.vue -->
<template>
  <div>
    Hello world
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  layout: 'editor',
})
onMounted(async () => {
  const { data } = await useAsyncData(() => queryContent().find())
  console.log(' ~ file: helloWork.vue:12 ~ data:', data)
})
</script>
```

The main problem arises when I use await setup in my unit test, as it times out before reaching any functionality in the Vue component. Removing it leads to a SyntaxError when using the mount method.

I've also tried using nuxt-vitest/utils, specifically mountSuspended and renderSuspended methods, but the queryContent result in HelloWorld component always returns null.

Questions:

Which approach is more appropriate for testing Vue components in a Nuxt Content environment?
How can I successfully use queryContent functionality while running content.test.ts?

Additional Information:

I'm using Vitest for testing, and here's my Vitest configuration:

```
// vitest.config.ts
import { defineVitestConfig } from 'nuxt-vitest/config'
import vitePluginSass from 'vite-plugin-sass'
import { createStyleImportPlugin } from 'vite-plugin-style-import'
import Vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import sass from 'sass'

export default defineVitestConfig({
  server: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5000,
    strictPort: true,
    origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
  },
  plugins: [
    vitePluginSass(),
    createStyleImportPlugin({}),
    Vue(),
  ],
  test: {
    passWithNoTests: true,
    dangerouslyIgnoreUnhandledErrors: true,
    testTimeout: 20000,
    globals: true,
    environmentOptions: {
      nuxt: {
        rootDir: __dirname,
        domEnvironment: 'jsdom',
      },
    },
    deps: {
      inline: [/@nuxt\/test-utils/],
    },
    environment: 'jsdom',
    
  },
})
```

Any insights or guidance on resolving these issues would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

I`ve tried setting up both nuxt-vitest/utils and @nuxt/test-utils. nuxt-vitest/utils`s mountSuspended method succesfully mounted my component , but queryContent was always null.
@nuxt/test-utils`s setup method leads to timeout crash , and removing it would show another error with mount issue which looks like this :

```
 FAIL  test/content.test.ts [ test/content.test.ts ]
[error] SyntaxError: At least one <template> or <script> is required in a single file component.
```